# Send Push Notification - It shows successful response but not showing any notifcation

Tags: go, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was trying to send push notification through fcm. In the response, I get all successful response. But I didn't get any notification. In other way, I tried to send notification directly from firebase console, and I get the notfication with the same token. So, I don't know what is the bug in this code. Token is okay. Response is also OK. but after executing code, I don't get any notification.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/base64"
    "log"
    "server/config"
    db "server/database"

    firebase "firebase.google.com/go/v4"
    "firebase.google.com/go/v4/messaging"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

func init() {
    config.Init()
    db.ConnectRedis()
}

var ctx = context.Background()

func getDecodedFireBaseKey() ([]byte, error) {
    fireBaseAuthKey := config.Env.FirebaseAuthKey
    decodedKey, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(fireBaseAuthKey)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return decodedKey, nil
}

func SendPushNotification(deviceTokens []string) error {
    decodedKey, err := getDecodedFireBaseKey()

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    opts := []option.ClientOption{option.WithCredentialsJSON(decodedKey)}

    app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, nil, opts...)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error in initializing firebase", err)
        return err
    }

    fcmClient, err := app.Messaging(ctx)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error getting Messaging client: %v\n", err)
    }

    response, err := fcmClient.SendMulticast(ctx, &messaging.MulticastMessage{
        Notification: &messaging.Notification{
            Title: "Congratulations!!",
            Body:  "You have just implement push notification",
        },
        Tokens: deviceTokens,
    })

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    log.Println("Response success count : ", response.SuccessCount)
    log.Println("Response failure count : ", response.FailureCount)

    return nil
}

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    deviceTokens, _ := db.RedisClient.SMembers(ctx,"fcmToken").Result()
    SendPushNotification(deviceTokens)

    r.Run()
}
```

Comment: Hey! I guess you need to apply the client code whatever it's browser or app notification to make sure it's properly rendered. Very likely the json you're sending is ok, however the client rendering code can't properly process it.

Comment: To give an update. Chrome says, "This site has been updated in the background". But Firefox provides the notification with well. Only a chrome issue.